# Django - select [column] AS

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have the following code:

```
MyModel.objects.values('foo','flu','fu').filter(part_of=pk)
```

which gives me the following dictionary:

```
{'foo': a, 'flu': b, 'fu': c}
```

This dictionary is serialized into a JSON response like so:

```
JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Is there a way I could rename  the key of `'flu'` into something while preserving the value?

So far I tried:

```
values[0]['new_flu'] = values[0].pop('flu')
```

Which I think is the usual Python way of renaming a dictionary key however this seems to have no effect and the JSON returned still contains `'flu'` instead of `new_flu`.

I feel like this could be simply solved by ALIAS eg.  `SELECT foo, flu AS new_flu, fu from ....`. What would be the Django alternative of this command? Or is there some other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options is to annotate query with names you needed:

```
from django.models import F
MyModel.objects.filter(part_of=pk).annotate(new_flu=F('flu')).values('foo','new_flu','fu')
```